# Hook add_attachment error

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks, actions

I am trying to optimize my images when uploading to website. I trying to write plugin, that will use hook 'add_attachment' and after attachment uploaded do image converting.

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'optimize_psio', 0);
// Action for optimizing on upload
function optimize_psio( $post_ID){
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-ps-image-optimizer-converter.php';
    $converter = new Ps_Image_Optimizer_Converter($post_ID);
    $converter->optimize();
}
```

The *optimize_psio* function works great when working standalone. But when I trying to register hook and upload image, I getting error:

> Post-processing of the image failed likely because the server is busy
> or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help.
> Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.

Image uploading, but not cropped and not converted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the code for `Ps_Image_Optimizer_Converter` is missing!

Comment: There only converting to webp function there and it was tested without action and worked.

Comment: You still need to share the class, all of the relevant code to answering the question is contained inside that class. You must edit your question to include it. I know you do not believe it is relevant, but you're also trying to figure out a problem and have come here and asked, so humour us, after all if it is indeed irrelevant it will be clear from the code and nobody will ask again

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell I found what is my error. Hook fires before image was cropped and that is why I can't optimize images that not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook **add_attachment** fires before images cropped via **wp_ajax_crop_image()**. That's why Wordpress trying to work with files, that is not existed for now.